# rsyncing using cygwin's rsync from the Windows Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, rsync

I am pushing a local file to a folder in a remote location using cygwin's rsync from the Windows Command Prompt.

The below command

```
D:\My Folder>C:/cygwin/bin/rsync.exe  -avh data.csv ec2-user@someserver.com::~"overhere/"
```

returns the error, "`failed to connect to someserver.com : connection timed out`"

When I try the following command to place the file in the remote location root folder,

```
D:\My Folder>C:/cygwin/bin/rsync.exe  -avh data.csv ec2-user@someserver.com~
```

it says "`sending incremental file list`" but I am not able to find the file in the root folder in the remote location.

What am I doing  wrong?

Comment: Hey, I would love to help you but need some more setup about your rsync setup so far. First, what windows version are you using and what OS is the server? Second did you set the windows path environment variables to cygwin?

Comment: Is there any proxy involved?

Comment: @CMPSoares I'm with Windows 7 and am looking for a solution which doesn't involve tampering with the 'environment variables'.

Comment: @foobar `ec2-user@someserver.com:~/overhere/` works great! Thanks. Please add this as the answer and I will award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout most likely occurs because there is no rsync daemon running on the server known as someserver.com.
Using :: after the remote host name will cause rsync to try to connect to the rsync daemon running on that machine. If you use : instead, rsync will attempt a shell access to copy your data.

Your second call to rsync.exe succeeds because rsync.exe -avh data.csv c2-user@someserver.com~ creates a copy of data.csv in your current working directory named ec2-user@someserver.com~.

If you use shell access, you can directly provide the path after the :, if using the rsync daemon, you have to provide the module name as configured in /etc/rsyncd.conf on the server after the ::. So in your case it is either ec2-user@someserver.com:~/overhere/ for shell access or ec2-user@someserver.com::MODULE for the daemon.
But as I suspect that you have no rsync daemon running on the remote machine, you'd have to install and configure it first for the second version to work. The first version will do through normal SSH access.

So as a first attempt you can try: D:\My Folder>C:/cygwin/bin/rsync.exe -avh data.csv ec2-user@someserver.com:overhere/
This will create a folder named overhere in the ec2-user's home directory on someserver.com if it doesn't already exist and copy the local data.csv into that directory.